# Limit rotation limits the wrong axis

Tags: bones, constraints

Ima having a problem where i limit my bone's rotation in the Y axis but in the scene it is limiting the X axis.

Here's a [gif](https://gyazo.com/e3a21ab272425b74fea20f2055725b5d)

Thanks guys in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraint is in "world space" switch it to "local space"

Comment: Tryied but did not work :S

Comment: I can think of two other options. Try to apply the rotation of the armature in object mode. Or select the armature and go to the Properties-Editor-->Object-->Transform-->Rotation-Mode

Comment: In object  i have XYZ euler and in armature, each bone is quaternion w x y z

Comment: Oh, another method would be to rotate the bone in edit mode by pressing ctrl+R. You can see which axes your bones are aligned to by going into the Properties-Editor-->Object-->Display-->Axis

Comment: So the axis they have in edit mode are the same as in pose mode?

Comment: If in pose mode you press "Ctrl+A" and Apply Pose as Rest Pose. The setup you have in Edit mode is the "rest pose"